# solution to "sum root to leaf numbers" problem

Tags: c++, binary-tree

Given a binary tree containing digits from 0-9 only, each root-to-leaf path could represent a number.

An example is the root-to-leaf path 1->2->3 which represents the number 123.

Find the total sum of all root-to-leaf numbers % 1003.

example:
if 1 is root, its left child is 2 and right child is 3 then,
The root-to-leaf path 1->2 represents the number 12.
The root-to-leaf path 1->3 represents the number 13.

Return the sum = (12 + 13) % 1003 = 25 % 1003 = 25.
original problem [is here](https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/sum-root-to-leaf-numbers/)

P.S: this is not homework, I'm preparing for college placements.
my attempt:

```
/**
 * Definition for binary tree
 * struct TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode *left;
 *     TreeNode *right;
 *     TreeNode(int x) : val(x), left(NULL), right(NULL) {}
 * };
 */
void DFS(TreeNode* root, string &temp, int *ans){
    if(!root)
    return;

    temp = temp + to_string(root->val);

    if(root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL && temp.length()!=0){
        *ans = (*ans + stoi(temp))%1003;
    }

    if(!root->left)
    DFS(root->left, temp, ans);
    if(!root->right)
    DFS(root->right, temp, ans);

    if(!temp.empty())
    temp.pop_back();
} 
int Solution::sumNumbers(TreeNode* A) {
    string temp = "";
    int ans = 0;
    DFS(A, temp, &ans);
    return ans%1003;
}
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: The solution is not correct. Its always returning 0

Comment: I agree that the question is not clear and it makes it hard to answer. I assumed that the code doesn't work as intended. Given that, I can see something strange in the lines `if(!root->left) DFS(root->left, temp, ans);`. Shouldn't it be `if(root->left) DFS(root->left, temp, ans);`? Same thing for the right node. Basically, you never go down in the tree if a node exists.

Comment: omg i cant believe im that silly. Thanks its done.

Comment: how do i close this question ?

Comment: Glad that I could help you. I'll put my answer and you can accept it.

Comment: Slight remark: 9876543210 is larger than 2**32 so it will not fit in a 31-bit signed `int` or a 32-bit `unsigned int`

Comment: And you do not need a string to accumulate digits, just multiply by 10 and add the new digit.

Comment: You can recurse unconditionally since you're properly handling null nodes on function entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

`if(!root->left) DFS(root->left, temp, ans);` should be

`if(root->left) DFS(root->left, temp, ans);`

Same thing for the right node. Basically, you never go down in the tree if a node exists.

---

Alternatively, you can simplify the code:

- Use integers instead of strings to make the computations lighter.
- Pass `temp` variable by copy, then you won't have to "pop_back" the last digit.
- Call `DFS` without checking if the pointer is null since it already checks at the beginning.
- Remove the last modulo operation since it was already done in `DFS`.

```
void DFS(TreeNode* root, int temp, int *ans){
    if(!root)
        return;

    temp = temp*10 + root->val;

    if(!root->left && !root->right)
        *ans = (*ans + temp)%1003;

    DFS(root->left, temp, ans);
    DFS(root->right, temp, ans);
} 
int Solution::sumNumbers(TreeNode* A) {
    int ans = 0;
    DFS(A, 0, &ans);
    return ans;
}
```

Comment: Applying the modulo at the end introduces a risk for overflow in the intermediate additions. And this kind of exercise is typically constructed to do exactly that.

Comment: @molbdnilo Yes, you're right. I'll edit the answer.